# Transform column value to the column_name in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, transform, feature-engineering

I have dataframe :

```
data= pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 0, 5],"B":[0,0,5],"C":[0,0,9]})
```

then I want to transform it into:

```
data= pd.DataFrame({"A": [A, '', ''],"B":['','',B],],"C":['','','C']})
```

then I want to combine the column value into one new column:

```
data= pd.DataFrame({"A": [A, '', ''],"B":['','',B],"C":['','','C'],"combine":['A','','B_C']})
```

Anyone can help me?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Check with `join` with `strip`

```
data2.apply('_'.join,1).str.strip('_')
Out[425]: 
0      A
1       
2    B_C
dtype: object
data2['combine']=data2.apply('_'.join,1).str.strip('_')
```

Comment: @DoniSuhartono where is C ? in data